# Stored Proc, how to select into multiple variables?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

My Stored Proc is not behaving how I would expect. I am expecting to populate multiple variables from 1 select statement.

Like this:

```
Declare @Phone nvarchar(30); 
Declare @Fax nvarchar(30); 

select @Phone = phone , @Fax = fax from customer where customerID = 1;
```

However, the variables are always blank after this select. I am sure the result set is scalar, and data actually exists.

Where is the obvious blunder, and thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `select * from customer where customerID = 1` returns any values?

Comment: How are you checking the values of the variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should work, I think (I'm sure someone will correct me!).

You're absolutly sure the data exists?

and if you add a

```
print @Phone
print @Fax
```

immediatly after, they're both blank?

Comment: I'll recheck again, just to be 200% sure.

Comment: You're right, data was the concern. Obviously the example I posted above was a simplification of the real thing, but I had an issue with the where clause. Thanks again!